# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘->’ token

Tags: c++, linked-list

It's giving me this error for lines 21 and 22, which are the ones I've noted. Judging from other cases with similar error messages, I've got a syntax error somewhere. I just can't figure out what.. Here's my .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "deque.h"

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *prev;
    node *next;
};

Deque::Deque(){
    count = 0;

    node->head->next = node->head;         //error on this line
    node->head->prev = node->head;         //and this one
}
```

Here's my header file:

```
# ifndef DEQUE_H
# define DEQUE_H


class Deque
{
private:
    int count;
    class node *head;
public:
    Deque();
    ~Deque();
    int size();
    void addFirst(int);
    void addLast(int);
    int removeFirst();
    int removeLast();
    int getFirst();
    int getLast();

};
#endif
```

Comment: `node` has no member called `head`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth lol beat me to it

Comment: You need to give your `node` some `head`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct code for these lines:

```
head->next = head;
head->prev = head;
```

Your variable is named `head`, and `node` is its type, but there is no member named `node` in your class `Deque`

Answer (score 0):

1. `struct node` has no member named `head`, which is a problem.
2. Where is your `node` variable coming from in `Dequeue()`?  Looks undefined given the code that you have posted.  `node` is a type, not a variable.
3. In C++ there is no need to prefix each declaration of a struct type variable with `struct`.  If it needs to be C compatible you can always `typedef` the struct as well.